# Need help run github project on window

Tags: node.js, mongodb, blockchain, ethereum

I'm good with PHP&MYSQL on Windows. But this project is Nodejs and Mongodb.
It's for a crypto decentralised exchange, and you can find the project at: karachain/DEx on github.

Can anyone help me run this on Windows system?
I don't understand the readme.

Answer (score 0):

> Okay I got it,
>
> Step 1 : you have to pull the code on your windows
>
> Step 2 : Install npm from here
>   https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-windows
>
> Step 3 : Open cmd and go to project directory via cd
>
> Step 4 : execute this command "npm install"
>
> Step 5 : execute this command "npm start"
>
> :) - nodeJS and reactJS projects are execute by this steps  Note: you
>   have to install npm at once, no need to reinstall for another project

Comment: Do i need rebuild or what should i do everytime edit config.js file?? Because when i edit config file, seem it change nothing in localhost

Comment: @LanCuong the above steps for run the project, I haven't any idea regarding config.js, generally in node projects we setup config.js file at once we don't need to change it every time.